# How to insert a dynamic list into sqlite3 query? sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I trying to use sqlite3 query like this one:

```
books = c.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", session["cart"])
```

Where session["cart"] is a dynamic list.
For example:
`session["cart"] = ['1', '7']`

I get an error as given in title while trying to execute it.

How may I insert whole list in the question mark placeholder?
I can't use multiple question marks, because their number may vary.

Does anyone has any clue? Or maybe better idea how to achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to format your python list into something sql can read, this is easily done with **str.join**

```
stringified_list = ", ".join(session["cart"])
books = c.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", stringified_list )
```

in case you are unfamiliar, str.join(iterable) will make a string with all the string representations of the items in the iterable separated by the str you called `join` on, i.e. `'---'.join([1,2,3])`
will produce `"1---2---3"` (a string)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I know this method, but I was completely fixed with idea that I may do so without additional variable.